# Using FontAwesome on Expandable List

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a little list right now and I want to use Font Awesome right carrot to indicate that the text is exapandable. I can put the font awesome  on any of the li items that dont have a ul under it. But if I try to add it to Item 3 then the icon does not show up. However it shows up for Item 1. Below is the code, simple little list that shos the FA being used in Item 1 which it will show up, but the exact same code is in the Item 3 but it won't show up.

```
<tr><td class="tcat"><strong>Categories</strong></td>{$inlinemodcol}</tr>
<tr>

<td class="trow1" colspan="2">
     <ul>
        <li><i class="fa icon-caret-right"></i>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li><i class="fa icon-caret-right"></i>Item 3
            <ul>
                <li>Item 3.1</li>
                <li>Item 3.2</li>
                <li>Item 3.3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 4
            <ul>
                <li>Item 4.1</li>
                <li>Item 4.2</li>   
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
```

The Javascript that this little menu uses to expand the menu:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('li')
        .css('pointer','default')
        .css('list-style-image','none');
    $('li:has(ul)')
        .click(function(event){
            if (this == event.target) {
                $(this).css('list-style-image',
                    (!$(this).children().is(':hidden')) ? 'url(plusbox.gif)' : 'url(minusbox.gif)');
                $(this).children().toggle('slow');
            }
            return false;
        })
        .css({cursor:'pointer', 'list-style-image':'url(plusbox.gif)'})
        .children().hide();
    $('li:not(:has(ul))').css({cursor:'default', 'list-style-image':'none'});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the javascript code you are using.

These lines:

`$(this).children().toggle('slow');`

and

`.children().hide();`

are hiding the `childrens` of `li` i.e. `i` and `ul` . So just change your javascript to hide only the `ul` children of `li` instead of hiding all childrens.

**Updated JS:**

```
$(function () {
    $('li')
        .css('pointer', 'default')
        .css('list-style-image', 'none');
    $('li:has(ul)')
        .click(function (event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).css('list-style-image', (!$(this).children().is(':hidden')) ? 'url(plusbox.gif)' : 'url(minusbox.gif)');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('slow'); //Changed
        }
        return false;
    })
        .css({
        cursor: 'pointer',
            'list-style-image': 'url(plusbox.gif)'
    })
        .children('ul').hide(); //Changed
    $('li:not(:has(ul))').css({
        cursor: 'default',
            'list-style-image': 'none'
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/JfGVE/157/